# Getting a "The OAuth identity of this script is invalid" error in a googleapps-script

Tags: google-apps-script

There's not much more to be said. I've tried searching for what this means, but can't find it. The script has been running fine for a few months and stopped 12 hours ago with no changes made to it. A manual run shows this error.

Comment: what service is this script using ? how does it run ? as a standalone app ? an embedded script ? there is maybe much more to tell... a site like this is all about programming issues, how could we answer a post that doesn't show/describe any piece of program at all ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I just clicked *Run* from the Script Editor and then requested the authorization to run.

Once I authorized the script the error didnt appear anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I was lucky - I just made coffee and when I tried the script again, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that you need to completely recreate the script project.

I had this problem crop up in a script housed on a spreadsheet. It only utilized the Mail & Spreadsheet services and happened randomly after zero changes for months. Tried just logging text and it wouldn't even work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, it was working great for months and then yesterday stopped working. I was able to work around the error by doing a "Debug" on the script (spider icon next to the "Run" icon in the toolbar). There were no debug errors and I was then able to successfully run the script again.